# ImageView setImageDrawable not working for ShapeDrawable

Tags: android

I've created a `ShapeDrawable` programmatically and want to display it in an `ImageView`. If I use `ImageView.setImageDrawable()`, I'm unable to see the `ShapeDrawable`. If I use `ImageView.setBackground()`, it works.

Why does `ImageView.setImageDrawable()` not work?

ImageView from the layout file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Activity's onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = 300;
    int height = 250;

    ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    drawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
    drawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);

    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    iv.setBackground(drawable);        // works
    //iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);   // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: It works but you have to  set a `LayoutParams` of the image before the `setImageDrawable` like `iv.setLayoutParams(newLinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`

Comment: @Eminem, that doesn't work either. I shouldn't have to set the width and height anyway since they are explicitly set in the layout XML, right?

Comment: you can try but I don't think that is a problem.did u after my comment call `setImageDrawable` or did you leave it just that?

Comment: @Eminem I added the code you suggested and called setImageDrawable(), and it didn't work.  The drawable did appear when I called setBackground(), and it filled the whole screen because the width and height were set to match parent.

Comment: @Eminem WRAP_CONTENT doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display a ShapeDrawable in an ImageView, your ShapeDrawable should have height and width defined. Add the below properties to your ShapeDrawable.

`drawable.setIntrinsicHeight(height);
 drawable.setIntrinsicWidth(width);`

Comment: I thought setBounds() was setting the width and height, but I see now there's a difference between a drawable's bounding rect and intrinsic width and height.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple View and just set its background drawable to the shape using setBackgroundDrawable.

The ImageView probably can't display your shape because it has no default size. You can give your shape a default sizer using sD.setIntrinsicWidth and sD.setIntrinsicHeight.